# Isotropic positive definite quadratic forms over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: quadratic-forms, integer-lattices

I don't know if this have any sense but, it is possible to have a positive definite $n$-ary quadratic form (over $\mathbb{Z}$ that is isotropic? Does the condition of positive definite made it impossible?

Hasse-Minkowski theorem will help in this case?

Comment: A positive definite form, by definition, can't evaluate to zero on a nonzero vector. So "positive definite" and "isotropic" are directly contradictory.

Comment: It can be semi positive definite (the $0$ quadratic form works)

Comment: Meanwhile, the very next layer here is switching to $p-adic$ numbers. In dimension 3, a positive form is anisotropic at an odd number of primes; meaning, for such a prime $p,$    there is an exponent $r$  such that $$ Q(x,y,z) \equiv 0 \pmod {p^r} $$    forces all three $x,y,z \equiv 0 \pmod p.$ (This is the product identity for the Hilbert symbol)  I recommend Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms.  See   http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/